# How to save groovy output to pipeline variable

Tags: python, object, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below code in the jenkisn pipeline:

```
   stage ("amd_distribution_input_transformation"){
        steps{
            script{
                    amd_distribution_input_transformation url: params.DOMAIN_DESCRIPTOR_URL, secret: params.CERDENITAL_ID
                }
            }
        }
```

amd_distribution_input_transformation.groovy content:

```
def call(Map parameters)
{
    def CREDENITAL_ID = parameters.secret
    def DOMAIN_DESCRIPTOR_URL = parameters.url
    sh '''
        python amd_distribution_input_transformation.py
      '''
    }             
}
```

in the amd_distribution_input_transformation.py some code is running, and at the end, it returns object named 'artifacts_list'

my question is, how can I assign the return obect from groovy file to pipeline variable.
BTW, if it helps, I can write the output to json file from the python code (and here I'm stuck on how eventually assign that file to the pipeline variable)

Comment: Your `sh` method needs a `returnStdout` argument for the Python script's JSON output to be received. Additionally, is your `call` method supposed to return a JSON String or a Groovy Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` command could catch only standard output from script.

So, you could not `return value from shell script`. You should print it.

And use `returnStdout:true` parameter for `sh` pipeline command to get printed value.

For example you have `my.py` python script

```python
import json

# a Python object (dict):
x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# print the result to transfer to caller:
print(y)
```

Then in pipeline you could get the json printed by python:

```groovy
def jsonText = sh returnStdout:true, script: "python my.py"
def json=readJSON text: jsonText

//print some values from json:
println json.city
println "name: ${json.name}"
```

---

Used pipeline steps:

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-sh-shell-script

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: Added example based on your script.

Comment: so it means at the end shOut will contain the python response (artifacts_list)? and then, how can I call/use it in my pipeline?

Comment: In python you have to do something like `print artifacts_list` then you'll get this value in groovy. And in groovy as minimum you could do `echo shOut`. I don't know what you want to do with it...

Comment: but how I can use/access shOut from pipeline?

Comment: Looks like you are extending your question. Please edit question and provide all details how json looks like and how would you like to use it...

Comment: Tnx, I will try and update. BTW, is there a second option, to save the python output to Linux file and then define pipeline variable which gets its value?

Comment: Sure. If it's a json file, then the same step could be used to load it but with other param `readJSON file: "filename.json"`