# Returning a Dictionary from python script to groovy

Tags: python, groovy

I'm trying to define a map in groovy pipeline, and in order to do that I'm calling a python script that creates a dictionary - which I want to convert to a map in the calling pipeline job.

I use

```
desiredMap = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'pythonScript.py").trim()
```

but the output is a string containing all the 'prints' from the python script.
Is there an easier way than formatting the string and creating the map on my own?

Comment: you could use json to pass a dictionary from python to groovy 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912140/how-to-save-groovy-output-to-pipeline-variable/58913964#58913964

Comment: Can u share your python script in order to see what you want to achieve?